# Why can't browser fully render the DOM many times per second like game-engines do, without struggling with performance?

Tags: javascript, performance, dom, game-engine, game-physics

I am trying to understand why it's a hard task for browsers to fully render the DOM many time per second, like game-engines do for their canvas. Games engines can perform many many calculation each frame, calculating light, shadows, physics etc`, and still keep a seamless frame rate.
Why browsers can't do the same, allowing full re-rendering of the DOM many times per second seamlessly?

I understand that rendering a DOM and rendering a Game scene are two completely different tasks, but I don't understand why the later is so much harder in terms of performance.

Please try to focus on specific aspects of rendering a DOM, and explain why games-engines don't face the same problems. For example- "browsers need to parse the HTML, while all the code of the game is pre-compiled and ready to run".

EDIT: I edited my question because it was marked as opinionated. I am not asking for opinions here, only facts. I am asking why browsers can't fully re-render the DOM 60 frames per second like game-engines render their canvas. I understand that browsers faces a more difficult task, but I don't understand why exactly. Please stick with informative answers only, and avoid opinions.

Comment: I don't think the DOM is slow at all in modern browsers, even mobile devices.

Comment: so why can't we update the full DOM 60 times per second like games are doing, calculating tons of light angels, shadows, interactions and game physics each frame

Comment: That's an absurd abuse of what a browser is intended to do.

Comment: but the question is why is it hard? why is it abuse? why can't we create a dom that could be rendered 60 per second and be fast like games

Comment: Browsers came into being to display structured information. They're not gaming platforms.

Comment: @kundasaba DOM stands for **Document** Object Model. HTML stands for Hyper **Text** Markup Language. If you try to modify HTML elements with the DOM to render a game, you're gonna have problems.

Comment: you have a no understanding of how hardware and software work - games talk directly to the graphics cards using tech such as openGL, direct draw in bespoke code - the DOM has to be very flexible and is a much high level layer.  

You can get closer to the machine layer inside a browser now using webGl, and webasm - but these as still sandboxed

Comment: @D.Pardal see my edit in the post. I am not asking for creating a game using DOM, I am asking what makes it hard for browsers to fully render the dom 60 times per second, while for game engines is easy

Comment: have a look here - this is what games do - they push very specific c style rendering code on the graphics card, the card does all the calcs for rendering - this isnt available in a browser as you are too high level - the browser has to go more generic rendering (unless you use webGL)
https://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/code/samples/glut_examples/examples/examples.html

Comment: Why is it hard to make a tractor do 150mph, when it's way easier for sports car to do it.  Or why cant my sports car plough the field.

Comment: @Keith, those are all valid questions that could have received detailed answers explaining how the engine of tractors and sport cars work differently, one focusing on power and one focusing on speed, and why it's hard to get both speed and power at the same time

Comment: In short, complex games don't use DOM. Graphics heavy apps eg: games are mostly based on canvas, and/or webgl. You should read about them how they efficiently make games for the browsers.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, games on the Web don't use the [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model) much. They use the faster [Canvas API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API). The DOM is made for changing content on a [*document*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document) (that's what the D in DOM stands for), so it is a really bad fit for games.

> How is it possible that my crappy phone can run Call Of Duty seamlessly, but it's so hard to write a big webpage that will run smoothly on it?

I never had performance problems with the DOM. Of course, if you update the whole `<body>` with a single `.innerHTML` assignment 60 times a second, I wouldn't be surprised if the performance is bad, because the browser needs to:

1. Parse the HTML and construct the DOM tree;
2. Apply styles and calculate the position of each element;
3. Render the elements.

Each of those steps is a lot of work for the CPU, and the process is mostly single-threaded in most browsers.

You can improve the performance by:

- **Never using `.innerHTML`.** `.innerHTML` makes the browser transform HTML into a DOM tree and vice-versa. Use `document.createElement()` and `.appendNode()`.
- **Avoid changing the DOM.** Change only the CSS styles, if possible.

Comment: But this is exactly my question - why is it so hard to create a dom that could be update the innerHTML 60 per second and stays fast, like games.

Comment: First of all thanks for you answer and patient:) But I already know and understand all of this, I am a web developer myself, what I don't understand is why game engines aren't suffering from the same problem. when you drive a car in the game, the engine should calculate the lights and shadows of tons of particles, and it doing it seamlessly

Comment: Because game engines don't need to parse any text format into a data structure, or calculate the styles for all elements the same way CSS does. The DOM isn't meant for performance.

Comment: so you are saying that the bottleneck is the parsing of the text and css?

Comment: games push special specific code into the graphics cards to do specific rendering  specifically for their game.  Browsers need to render lots of different things -are much high level applications, and generic
https://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/code/samples/glut_examples/examples/examples.html

Comment: @developer this is actually the best answer here until now. I am still waiting for better detailed answers, but if you'll write this comment in as an answer, and no one will give a better detailed one soon in the following days, i'll pick yours.

Comment: @kundasaba To answer your question `why is it so hard to create a dom that could be update the innerHTML`, firstly the "hard" and "slow" are relative here. It all boils down to how heavy your DOM is and how frequently you let the browser re-render everything. There are efficient ways of DOM manipulation like batch updates and intelligent diffing algorithms that modern web apps use. But that's all for web apps; for games these won't work as it's not a document you're rendering. They're graphics and it's based on the canvas api or webgl mostly.

Answer (score 0):

Games are programs written to do operations specific to themselves - they are written in low level languages asm/c/c++ or at least languages that have access to machine level operations.  When it comes to graphics, games are able to push programs into the graphics cards for rendering: drawing vectors and colouring / rasterization

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rasterisation#:~:text=Rasterisation%20(or%20rasterization)%20is%20the,which%20was%20represented%20via%20shapes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rasterisation#:%7E:text=Rasterisation%20(or%20rasterization)%20is%20the,which%20was%20represented%20via%20shapes))

they also have optimised memory, cpu usage, and IO.

Browsers on the other hand are applications, that have many requirements.

Primarily designed to render HTML documents, via the creation of objects which represent the html elements.  Browsers have got a more complex job, as they support multiple version of the dom and document types (DTD), and associated security required by each DTD.

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_type_declaration#:~:text=A%20document%20type%20declaration%2C%20or,of%20HTML%202.0%20%2D%204.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_type_declaration#:%7E:text=A%20document%20type%20declaration%2C%20or,of%20HTML%202.0%20%2D%204.0)).

and have to support rending a very generic set of documents - one page is not the same as another. Have to have libraries for IO, CSS parsing, image parsing (JPEG, PNG, BMP etc.....) and movie players and associated codecs, audio players and their codecs, and web cams support.  Additionally they support the JavaScript code environment (not just the language - but IO and event handling) - also have historic support for COM, Java Applets.

This makes them very versatile tools, but heavy weighted - they carry a lot of baggage.

The graphic aspects can never be quite as performant as a dedicated program in this aspect, as the API they provide for such operations is always running at a higher level.

Even the Canvas API (as the name suggests) is a layer of abstraction above the lower level rendering libraries. and each layer of abstraction adds a performance hit.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API

For a better graphics performance there is now a new standard available in browsers call webGL - though this is still an API, and runs in a sandbox - so still will not be as performant as dedicated code

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebGL

Even games using game engines: Unity, Unreal will be accessing graphical features, CPU, memory, and IO in much more a dedicated fashion then browsers would - as the game engines themselves provide dedicated rendering and rasterization functions, that the developer can use in their games for optimised graphical features..  Browser cant as they have to cover many generic cases, but not specific requirements.

https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/Engine/index.html

https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/procedural-sky-19-1

Answer (score -2):

Generally , it's depend about the game . the most powerful games are developed in C++ or C engine , so they are directly in touch with the memory and use the full power of  processor.

Instead to web pages based on DOM , they are wrote it by interpreted language like JavaScript. Also , the problem can be from the server if the webpage it's deployed not correctly or in a bad slow server .